# sum of cubs in excel

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel we can use sumsq() to do the sum of squares in an area or a set of several areas. How can I do the sum of cubs or write a module that behave the same way?
I had some success with sumproduct() but in is not as flexible as sumSQ(). Any answer in Excel-VBA

Answer (score 0):

If data is in A1:A10, you can use `=SumProduct(A1:A10,A1:A10,A1:A10)`

If you want to write a udf

```
Function SumCu(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim sum As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    dat = r.Value2
    sum = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(dat, 2)
        sum = sum + dat(i, j) ^ 3
    Next j, i
    SumCu = sum
End Function
```

or more generally

```
Function SumPwr(r As Range, Pwr As Single) As Variant
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim sum As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    dat = r.Value2
    sum = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(dat, 2)
        sum = sum + Val(dat(i, j)) ^ Pwr
    Next j, i
    SumPwr = sum
End Function
```